# How to use extends condition in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

Let's say I have a function getRefCollection that accepts input is a class extends by AbstractModel

```
function getRefCollection<T>(Collection: new (tenant: string) => T extends AbstractModel<I> ? T : never) {
    return new Collection(this.tenantId || '').getModel()
  }
```

And a class

```
class ReportTenant extends AbstractModel<IReport> {
  constructor(tenant: string) {
    super({ name: MODEL.reports, tenant })
  }
}
```

when I call the getRefCollection function with input is ReportTenant

```
getRefCollection(ReportTenant)
```

Typescript show errors :

```
Argument of type 'typeof ReportTenant' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (tenant: string) => never'.
  Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'new (tenant: string) => ReportTenant' is not assignable to type 'new (tenant: string) => never'.
      Type 'ReportTenant' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&target=3&jsx=0&module=1&preserveWatchOutput=false&ts=4.7.4&removeComments=true#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguacIFkB7AEwFNkAeASQD4EBvAWACgEEAVATwAdSEAuBFRZsIpAHbBxEKsUGQoAS3EBzEQkkBbUvOjK1rJIXEKArvEJQAFPQ3BtAGgRjJ0hAF9BtrToQL9Ti5SELpKqh4AlAzqogAWimAAdD4IALx22jHO8UlB0rJpzhLB6u7qKqQQAEqkAGYAwoTIyKTwisYU7DRWjc2tEO3iguKkAO4IVnkhfnqqUal07AikAB4uxBjYCnhEZJS0CAD8HAIapABupFBRTIZsUJWmUOJn470tbcaTOYlTshGJCoEEjkKwRUrlSq7UE3LIPCBPF4Ack0IOQSIhzDKzBYyjEUFqcD4VBq3EsiFubB8oX0LGxLBQaAwpPJ7GKblW602OBg8Gh%20xZUAgdEpRhM0HMEEsk3Z038c2idz8pl41m89l8SIeZKFYCRgVlkUx9OYeKuhNgxMFEEamm0blFsGMLjlswMJsZ6AQ1tt9ogbNciE5Eg2WB5OzR1B9hDtEmFirYTvFUEl0qmNIVorYYBVVxsGU12vJeoNgaNSogPyBNQaTQ%20Ay%201oDwXBhmx7iAA)

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete example using https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/Q, there are some types missing

Comment: Hi Lin Du, I added code to playground. please take a look. Thanks

Comment: ① Please [edit] to put your [mre] as plaintext in the question itself; a playground link is a great supplement but it's not sufficient by itself; I'd do the edit but I don't have copyright on your externally-hosted code so I won't touch it. ② What are you actually trying to accomplish that [this version](https://tsplay.dev/N7qKqW) fails to do?  Right now I don't see a motivation for your generic or your conditional type, and since `ReportTenant` and `ReportContentTenant` have incompatible `Type` properties, your typing would prohibit you from calling `getRefCollection()` on one to the other.